# In which size to cut design for @2x iPhone 6/5/5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6-plus

I've read all the questions about this issue, all the web articles but still can't get it the right way.
I designed the app for iPhone 6+ (2208x1242), now I the PSD that I want to cut. For what size I need to resize in order to cut it the right size for iPhone 6/5/5S?

Just can't figure it out, so please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link with the resolution for all the other iPhone devices:
http://iphoneresolution.com/

You should just resize the background and cut the button and all other UI elements, if the elements need to be resized take care in resizing them by maintaining the aspect ratio.

Cheers, 
I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Reported screen size is in the code. Actual screen size is in comments.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    device = @"iPhone Classic"; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
    // Classic has a resolution of 480 × 320
    if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 1.0f ) {
        device = @"iPhone Classic";
    // Retina has a resolution of 960 × 640
    } else if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 2.0f ) {
        device = @"iPhone Retina35";
    // Retina 4" has a resolution of 1136 x 640
    } else if (screenSize.height == 568 || screenSize.width == 568 ) {
        device = @"iPhone Retina4";
    // iPhone 6 has a resolution of 1334 by 750
    } else if (screenSize.height == 667 || screenSize.width == 667 ) {
        device = @"iPhone 6";
    // iPhone 6 Plus has an actual size of 2208 × 1242 and resolution of 1920 by 1080
    // Reported size is 736 x 414
    } else if (screenSize.height == 736 || screenSize.width == 736 ) {
        device = @"iPhone 6 Plus";
        }

} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        device = @"iPad Classic"; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        if(deviceScale == 1.0f) {
            device = @"iPad Classic";
        } else if (deviceScale == 2.0f) {
            device = @"iPad Retina";
        }
}
```